# Sed script that will find a match in a line, and the change another part of that line

Tags: sed, backreference

I'm trying to change the "FS" type of the lines containing c1t1 from ufs to ext2 and change c1t1 to c1t2 everywhere on those lines. This is what the file looks like:

```
#device     device      mount       FS  fsck    mount   mount
#to mount   to fsck     point       type    pass    at boot options
#

#/dev/dsk/c1d0s2 /dev/rdsk/c1d0s2 /usr      ufs 1   yes -

fd  -   /dev/fd fd  -   no  -
/proc   -   /proc   proc    -   no  -
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s1   -   -   swap    -   no  -
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s0   /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s0  /   ufs 1   no  -
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s6   /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s6  /usr    ufs 1   no  -
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s4   /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s4  /var    ufs 1   no  -
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s5   /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s5  /local  ufs 2   yes -
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s3   /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s3  /usr/openwin    ufs 2   yes -

/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s0   /dev/rdsk/c1t0d0s0  /opt    ufs 3   yes -
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s3   /dev/rdsk/c1t0d0s3  /export/user1   ufs 3   yes nosuid
/dev/dsk/c1t1d0s0   /dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s0  /usr/local  ufs 3   yes -

/dev/dsk/c1t1d0s3   /dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s3  /export/user3   ufs 3   yes nosuid  
/dev/dsk/c2t0d0s0   /dev/rdsk/c2t0d0s0  /export/home    ufs 4   yes nosuid  
/dev/dsk/c2t0d0s3   /dev/rdsk/c2t0d0s3  /casa6  ufs 4   yes -
/dev/dsk/c2t3d0s0   /dev/rdsk/c2t3d0s0  /export/user2   ufs 5   yes nosuid  
/dev/dsk/c2t3d0s3   /dev/rdsk/c2t3d0s3  /stage  ufs 5   yes -

# ringer.cs.utsa.edu:/usr/local/news    -   /usr/local/news nfs -   yes retry=10    
ringer.cs.utsa.edu:/var/mail    -   /var/mail   nfs -   yes retry=10,actimeo=0  
#ringer.cs.utsa.edu:/var/spool/news -   /var/spool/news nfs -   yes retry=10
#ringer.cs.utsa.edu:/answerbook -   /answerbook nfs -   yes retry=10

swap    -   /tmp    tmpfs   -   yes -
```

This is all I've been able to figure out:

```
s/(^\/dev\/dsk\/c1t1.*)ufs(.*$)/$1ext2$2/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your search might benefit from a capture-and-replace:

```
sed -e 's/^\(.*dsk\/\)c1t1\(.*\)ufs\(.*\)$/\1c1t2\2ext2\3/g' some_file
```

It's not that readable and there are other ways to do it, but `\( \)` captures something. In the above example, I've captured three things, and when I want to dump them back in I refer to them in the following way (in the order of capture):

```
\1 \2 \3
```

Comment: Ah thanks that works I was pretty confused by the back referencing. Makes sense now.

Comment: Yeah. It's really confusing because the `\1` is just passed right in next to the text or spaces (or whatever we captured)
that comes after. It's often hard to read as a result.

Comment: Yeah it gets real nasty when a lot of slash, backslashes and all that are in there.

Comment: If you use `sed -r` you can catch the groups with simple `(...)` instead of `\(...\)`

Answer (score 3):

When the syntax is a bit confusing, sometimes it is time to use `awk`:

```
awk '$1~/c1t1/ {$4="ext2"; sub("c1t1","c1t2",$0)}1' file
```

#### Explanation

- `$1~/c1t1/` checks if the first field contains `c1t1`. If so, performs `{}`.
- `$4="ext2"` sets 4th field to "ext2".
- `sub("c1t1","c1t2",$0)` replaces all `c1t1` with `c1t2` throughout the line (`$0`).
- `1` prints all the lines.

You can execute it and redirect to another file: `awk ... file > new_file`.

#### Test

```
$ awk '$1~/c1t1/ {$4="ext2"; sub("c1t1","c1t2",$0)}1' file

#device     device      mount       FS  fsck    mount   mount
#to mount   to fsck     point       type    pass    at boot options
#

#/dev/dsk/c1d0s2 /dev/rdsk/c1d0s2 /usr      ufs 1   yes -

fd  -   /dev/fd fd  -   no  -
/proc   -   /proc   proc    -   no  -
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s1   -   -   swap    -   no  -
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s0   /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s0  /   ufs 1   no  -
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s6   /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s6  /usr    ufs 1   no  -
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s4   /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s4  /var    ufs 1   no  -
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s5   /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s5  /local  ufs 2   yes -
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s3   /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s3  /usr/openwin    ufs 2   yes -

/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s0   /dev/rdsk/c1t0d0s0  /opt    ufs 3   yes -
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s3   /dev/rdsk/c1t0d0s3  /export/user1   ufs 3   yes nosuid
/dev/dsk/c1t2d0s0 /dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s0 /usr/local ext2 3 yes -

/dev/dsk/c1t2d0s3 /dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s3 /export/user3 ext2 3 yes nosuid
/dev/dsk/c2t0d0s0   /dev/rdsk/c2t0d0s0  /export/home    ufs 4   yes nosuid  
/dev/dsk/c2t0d0s3   /dev/rdsk/c2t0d0s3  /casa6  ufs 4   yes -
/dev/dsk/c2t3d0s0   /dev/rdsk/c2t3d0s0  /export/user2   ufs 5   yes nosuid  
/dev/dsk/c2t3d0s3   /dev/rdsk/c2t3d0s3  /stage  ufs 5   yes -

# ringer.cs.utsa.edu:/usr/local/news    -   /usr/local/news nfs -   yes retry=10    
ringer.cs.utsa.edu:/var/mail    -   /var/mail   nfs -   yes retry=10,actimeo=0  
#ringer.cs.utsa.edu:/var/spool/news -   /var/spool/news nfs -   yes retry=10
#ringer.cs.utsa.edu:/answerbook -   /answerbook nfs -   yes retry=10

swap    -   /tmp    tmpfs   -   yes -
```

Comment: Fedorqui, he says that wants to change every `c1t1`. It would be better a global `sub()`, and also don't limit the comparison to the first field.

Comment: @Birei mmmm from `and change c1t1 to c1t2 everywhere on those lines` I understand it refers just to the lines matching the first condition. I cannot see the difference.

Comment: Ok. Fine, then. Different interpretations.

Comment: No problem, it wasn't very clear. From the accepted answer I see that it was this way.

Comment: Thanks, however it had to be a sed command. I'm trying to practice all the complicated stuff so I'll be prepared for my test coming out.

Comment: Ok I see @MarcusLorenzana. I would suggest you to use other field delimiters (`sed 's#one#two#g` is the same as `sed 's/one/two/g`) when you are handling strings with slashes. It will help to understand what is string and what is `sed` parts.

Comment: Ah thanks that is good to know. It will help with the readability.